# How do I modify the value of Mono in non-blocking fashion?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive-programming

I am calling a third party library that returns value as type - `Mono<String>`. I have to modify the value of that string, lets say keep only the first 5 characters if the string is longer than that and return `Mono<String>` again. How do I implement this? I have tried to block the Mono to extract string value and then substring it but that violates reactive paradigm.

```
Mono<Stirng> myVal = getValueFromService();
Mono<String> myShortenedString = //???
return myShortenedString;
```

Comment: Did you try with `flatMap` on `myVal` to modify and return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mono is a monad, so you can either use [map](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) or [flatMap](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) to transform the value it contains.

*map* is useful to transform the value using a "blocking" function. Example:

```java
Mono<String> myVal = Mono.just("test");
Mono<String> truncated = myVal.map(value -> value.substring(1, 3));
truncated.subscribe(System.out::println); // prints "es"
```

*flatMap* is useful when the transforming function itself returns a Mono. It "flattens" the result, to return a `Mono<T>` instead of a `Mono<Mono<T>>`. Example:

```java
Mono<String> transform(String value) {
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> value.substring(1, 3));
}

Mono<String> myVal = Mono.just("test");
Mono<String> truncated = myVal.flatMap(value -> transform(value));
truncated.subscribe(System.out::println); // prints "es"
```